# Is the "addition rule" an axiom of probability theory or why does it always holds?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Is the "addition rule" an axiom of probability theory or why does it always holds?

Reading the book "*Probability and Statistics for Computer Scientists - Baron, Michael*", I come across the following rule of joint probability distribution, which I always see referred to in other texts.

Having studied the axioms of probability, there only seem to be three such axioms, none of which look like the "addition rule" below.

So, why is this rule stated without proof everywhere I look?

Please, give an answer elaborate enough that a computer scientist will understand :-)

**Addition Rule:**
$$P_X(x)=P\{X=x\}=\sum_yP_{(X,Y)}(x,y)$$

$$P_Y(y)=P\{Y=y\}=\sum_xP_{(X,Y)}(x,y)$$

Comment: Presumably we are assuming that $P$ is a *discrete* probability distribution, otherwise the sums are not valid. The event $\{X=x\}$ is the disjoint union over all $y$ of the events $\{(X, Y)=(x, y)\}$.

Comment: If the events are mutually disjoint, and there are a finite number or they are countably infinite, then you can use addition.  This is in effect one of [Kolmogorov's probability axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms#Third_axiom)

Comment: @DustanLevenstein - Suppose I have a random variable $X$ with $p(X=a)=1/4$. Now suppose I create another random variable $Y$. Wouldn't it be possible for the joint distribution to not satisfy $p(X=a)=1/4$ when summed over all values of $y$? I mean, I could just define some random join distribution, couldn't I?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen Well, if you did such a thing then your new joint distribution for $X$ and $Y$ would be inconsistent with your old distribution for $X$.

Comment: But then the addition rule may not hold in general, right?

Comment: What I want to know is whether the addition rule is something that always hold no matter how the joint distribution is defined.

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen By definition, if you have a joint probability distribution on $X$ and $Y$, then you have an associated probability distribution on $X$, obtained by the formula you have given in your question. What you have suggested doing is "assigning" a probability distribution to $X$ which is completely different from the associated distribution on $X$. It's just nonsensical - you've effectively created two random variables with the same name.

Comment: Aha, so X considered in a probability space by itself is a completely different thing from X considered in a probability space with Y? They are two different X's?

Comment: Well, yes, you are defining two different $X$'s. It's kind of like saying "Let $(x, y) = (2, 3)$" and then later saying "Let $x=5$"; the two statements are in inherent conflict with one another. If you see something like this in literature, then hopefully it's a case where the context of the former statement is no longer relevant by the time you get to the latter one. Otherwise it's a pretty big mistake.